# Internal connection fatal error in opening connection

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, exception, web-config

In Asp.net mvc, I tried to open a sql connection, but it always gives me invalid connection fatal error.
Here is my following code:

In Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>    
 <add name="test" connectionString="Data Source=test,3306;Initial catalog=test;User Id=xxxxx;password=xxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

In Controller class:

```
var sql = "select * from users where email = \"" + model.Email + "\" and password = \"" + model.Password +\"";
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("return url = "+sql);
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString;
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dr.Read();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("output = " + dr.HasRows);
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("exception " + e.ToString());
            }


        }
```

It gives me following exception on conn.open();

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 18
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong in my code.

Comment: When you are using the `using` statement, you dont need to explicitly close your connection!

Comment: Ok. But still it gives me an error on conn.open()

Answer (score 2):

```
 public MySqlConnection GetMySqlConnection(string dataBase, string server,uint port,string userID,string pass)
 {
            MySqlConnectionStringBuilder myBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            myBuilder.Database = dataBase;
            myBuilder.Server = server;
            myBuilder.Port = port;
            myBuilder.UserID = userID;
            myBuilder.Password = pass;

            MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(myBuilder.ConnectionString);

            myconn.Open();
            return myconn;
  }
```

**Description:**
You should use MySql instead of MS SQL.
Install MySql connector net and MySql for Visual Studio ("just google them")

After install:

1. you must to add MySql.Data in References
2. in your class: using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;